# How to fetch record from two Ms.Access tables in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am making a railway reservation system in which I want the user to see his booking history.  In the reservation system  there is multiple login facility . Many users can create account and book tickets  . So, a user can check his bookings which were made from his account . Due to this reason , I thought that I should compare the username of the currently opened account with the account username column present in the database .  If the username of the currently opened account matches with the account username in the database , then it will fetch all those records under that name but when I try to execute, it gives me an error.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form12   

    Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Users\AMEN\Documents\Railway.accdb"
    Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim tables As DataTableCollection
    Dim source1 As New BindingSource

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MyConn = New OleDbConnection
        MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
        ds = New DataSet
        tables = ds.Tables
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select [T.Tnumber], [T.P_Name], [T.Age],[T.Train_Name], [T.Seat_No], [T.Berth],[t.R_Name], [t.Starting_Point],[t.Destination], [t.Departure], [t.Arrival], [t.Fare] from Table2 ,Table1 where T.PNR_Number=t.PNR_Number and T.Account_User=My.Settings.Username", MyConn)
        da.Fill(ds, "Table2")
        Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
        source1.DataSource = view
        DataGridView1.DataSource = view
    End Sub
End Class
```

I think something is wrong with da.Fill(ds, "Table2") but I don't know how to correct it.

Comment: Hey Nancy! Do you think posting the error that you get would be helpful?

Comment: Thanks for replying . It says OleDbException was unhandled at da.Fill(ds, "Table2")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `SELECT` statement you are comparing against My.Settings.Username, and I am imagining that this string doesn't exist in your db. You want the value inside the My.Settings.Username, we can just use string concatenation to add that to the end (as long it is a string!).

```
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select [T.Tnumber], [T.P_Name], [T.Age],[T.Train_Name], [T.Seat_No], [T.Berth],[t.R_Name], [t.Starting_Point],[t.Destination], [t.Departure], [t.Arrival], [t.Fare] from Table2 ,Table1 where T.PNR_Number=t.PNR_Number and T.Account_User=" + My.Settings.Username, MyConn)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it still gives me an error on the same line . Actually I have made a reservation system in which there are multiple login facility  . So, a user can check his bookings which were made from his account . Due to this reason , I thought that I should compare the username with the account username present in the database ( I will add it in database too ) . If the username of the currently opened account matches with the account username in the database , then it will fetch all those records under that name